# Looking for a powershell script that takes latest txt file in directory and searches for keyword "RequriedString"

Tags: powershell, monitoring, string-search, logfile-analysis

```
$dir = "C:\temp"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter filename*.txt -Path $dir | Sort-Object 
LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 
$SEL = get-content $latest
if( $SEL -imatch "error" )
{
      Write-Host 'Errors found in the log file'
      #send email code to be added
}
else
{
      Write-Host 'No Errors'
}
```

I have tried this code and it works well at the moment. But wanted to make sure the code works even if there are two latest text files at the same given time.

Comment: Have you tried... anything? Plenty of existing questions already asking how to get the last modified file, searching a text file, sending an email, etc.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried **yourself**. SO is not a platform where you can 'order' a script, you need to put in your own effort, explain what does and does not work there so we can help you.

Comment: Edited my question with more info on what is tried from myend

Comment: As for this... [But wanted to make sure the code works even if there are two latest text files at the same given time.], that is not a PowerShell issue or a control. That is all Windows proper. You are only selecting the first one, so, your concern should not be a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**File-system timestamps**, at least as reported via .NET and therefore via PowerShell, use the [`System.DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime) data type, whose **resolution is "one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second"**.

**I don't know if it's *actually* possible, but at the very least it seems *highly unlikely* that two or more files would end up with the exact same timestamp.**

If you don't want to take any chances, you can use the following approach:

```
$dir = 'C:\temp'

$latest = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter filename*.txt -LiteralPath $dir |
            Group-Object LastWriteTime |
              Select-Object -ExpandProperty Group -Last 1

if ($latest | Select-String 'error') {
  Write-Verbose -Verbose 'Errors found in the log file'
  #send email code to be added
}
else {
  Write-Verbose -Verbose 'No Errors'
}
```

Note:

- The above uses the `LastWriteTime` rather than the `LastAccessTime` property, because presumably you're interested in when the files were last *modified*.
- [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Group-Object) implicitly outputs its object sorted by the grouping criterion.
- `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Group -Last 1` takes the last group, representing the file(s) with the *latest* modification timestamp, and outputs the file-system info comprising that group (via the `.Group` property of the objects output by `Group-Object`).
- [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-String) accepts (multiple) file-system info objects via the pipeline and by default performs case-insensitive matching of the given regex against the files' contents.